# Mailgun 401 forbidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, unauthorized

send email with react, node using mailgun

I try to send a email message by using mailgun. I use node.js (nest.js) and this is my js file. What should I change? I got this Error Unauthorized, forbidden

```
const FormData = require("form-data");
const Mailgun = require("mailgun.js");



const mailgun = new Mailgun(FormData);

const mg = mailgun.client({
  username: "api",
  key:
    process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY
});



app.post("/sendMail", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;

  // Check if required fields are present
  if (!name || !email || !message) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "Name, email, and message are required fields" });
  }

  mg.messages
    .create("sandbox-123.mailgun.org", {
      from: "Excited User <mailgun@sandbox-123.mailgun.org>",
      to: [email],
      subject: "Hello",
      text: message,
      html: `<h1>${name} says:</h1><p>${message}</p>`,
    })
    .then((msg) => {
      console.log("Email sent successfully:", msg);
      res.send({ message: "Email sent" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error sending email:", err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send email" });
    });
});
```